# How to view the Safari history, pages opened on current device?

Tags: macos, safari, browser-history

I rarely use a Mac, but I often use an iPhone and an iPad. I needed to find a page in the history of Safari that I once browsed with a Mac. But I found that in Safari the history is completely transparent, there are all visits from all my Apple devices. There are no icons or information from which device I opened the sites. How can I filter history by current device only? On Chrome you can filter by device...

Comment: I don't think there's currently any way to determine the device by looking at the history.

Comment: One can always turn off history syncing and avoid this problem in the future. Also keep in mind that by default Safari on MacOS keeps one year of history so if  'once'  was more than year ago you will not find it anyway (you can have longer history by changing appropriate setting)